# Installing PostgreSQL and `createdb` with Terminal

Tags: postgresql, terminal, homebrew

**After installing `PostgreSQL` from the `terminal` with `Homebrew`...**

➜ ~ brew link postgresql

```
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.2_1: 3,186 files, 35.3MB

To relink: brew unlink postgresql && brew link postgresql
```

➜ ~ brew services restart postgresql

```
Successfully stopped postgresql (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)

Successfully started postgresql (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
```

➜ ~ createdb 'test'

```
createdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No server file or directory

Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

---

I would like to be able to run strictly from terminal and not be subject to using the PSequel GUI...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

## My main issue was:

➜ ~ createdb 'test'

```
createdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No server file or directory  
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

## this issue was simply solved by:

➜ ~ postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres

## which invocated the database directory...

```
2019-05-06 14:20:37.367 EDT [41854] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432  
2019-05-06 14:20:37.367 EDT [41854] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432  
2019-05-06 14:20:37.367 EDT [41854] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"  
2019-05-06 14:20:37.384 EDT [41854] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

## keeping that running, and opening a new-tab on my terminal:

➜ ~ createdb 'test'

➜ ~ psql 'test'

```
psql (11.2)

Type "help" for help.

test=#
```

---

## Something else of use during my debugging:

***remove old database files (this is dangerous)***

➜ ~ rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres

***followed-up with***

➜ ~ initdb /usr/local/var/postgres

`initdb` is not used to create a "new database"

[As Documented in the Manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/creating-cluster.html) you need it to create a "cluster" or "data directory" which then stores databases created with `createdb`

**Quote from the manual:**

> Before you can do anything, you must initialize a database storage area on disk. We call this a database cluster. (The SQL standard uses the term catalog cluster.) A database cluster is a collection of databases that is managed by a single instance of a running database server
>
> [...]
>
> In file system terms, a database cluster is a single directory under which all data will be stored. We call this the data directory or data area

In short: `initdb` creates the necessary directory layout on the harddisk to be able to create and manage databases.

It's a necessary part of the *installation* process of a Postgres server.